# Refactor class name capitalization in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, refactoring, capitalization

I've found some inconsistency in my class naming convention, some classes had suffix 'DTO', others 'Dto'. I've tried to fix it, but then I've got some problems.

I've refactored 'Dto' to 'DTO', and everything seemed to work, but after restarting Eclipse I've seen the class named with old 'Dto' prefix, while the class references are refactored correctly.

I know Windows has serious issues with changing the capitalization of the file names, that operation (usually?) doesn't work when made from file explorer (or however it is called). I'm not Windows programmer, but I'd expect, however, that file rename should work correctly when using Windows API... The question is, does Eclipse use it correctly, and how to force him to do that.

I've tried also refactoring to the other name and then back to correct one, but that 'trick' didn't work in Eclipse, so I'd have to change the name of the file forth and back manually.

Is there any safe procedure of making such refactoring? Unfortunatelly, I have no option of using programmer-friednly operating system so I have to do that in Windows...

I'm using IBM RAD 9.0 (Eclipse with IBM plugins) and Windows 7.

Comment: The Eclipse way of refactoring is `Refactor` -> `Rename`. Renaming classes will also change the file name (and vice versa). Did you simply change the file name outside of Eclipse?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Actually, In Eclipse, but clicking on the file name in package explorer (which has worked, eventually). At first I've refactored clicking on class name in java editor. In both casing, changing the capitalization alone was not working because it was not detected as file name change (well, it changed the references, but not the file name on the disc).

Comment: Hmmm ... This usually will be done together. This is strange. Maybe the file you renamed was not in a source path?

Comment: It seems that Windows has ignored the capitalization change. He's doing that when changing file names in file explorer...

Comment: I am also using Windows. And it works like a charm. It must be something else. Could you provide some screenshots showing the issue?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I'm not able to post images from my workspace. So you say, you have no issues with refactoring UserDto to UserDTO, for example? Maybe the Eclipse version is important, I've added details.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2 (under Windows 7). And - yes - I havo no issues. I just tested it: Renaming a class `SomeDto` to `SomeDTO` worked in call cases. I renamed the class file and the class itself was changed. I renamed the class and the file name was changed. I tested it with a public class and a package private class. I even put two package private classes into the file, and it was correctly refactored. I'm sorry, but I think I can't help you.

Comment: OK thanks. Maybe it was a one-time-only issue... IBM RAD has many issues, sometimes even basic functions doesn't work, maybe it's time to create a new workspace etc.